# jaxws-maven-plugin wsgen on test endpoint

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I'm trying to get maven 3 to run wsgen against two web service endpoints. One is a 'production' endpoint, located under src/main/java, and the other is a 'test' endpoint that is located under src/test/java.

The problem is, wsgen does not find the 'test' sei class as (presumably) it only has src/main/java on the classpath. It is not possible to directly set the wsgen classpath using jaxws-maven-plugin (there's no config element for it).  I've tried binding to the generate-test-sources phase but no joy

Here's the pom snippet:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- this works fine -->
                <execution>
                    <id>Production</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <protocol>soap1.1</protocol>
                        <sei>com.foo.ws.ProductionEndPoint</sei>
                        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsgen/src</sourceDestDir>
                        <destDir>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsgen/classes</destDir>
                        <packageName>com.foo.ws</packageName> 
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- this fails with Class Not Found on the sei class -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <id>Test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <protocol>soap1.1</protocol>
                        <sei>com.foo.ws.TestEndPoint</sei>
                        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsgen/src</sourceDestDir>
                        <destDir>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsgen/classes</destDir>
                        <packageName>com.foo.ws.test</packageName> 
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.4</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: Oh, and I tried the wsgen-test goal too, but whilst that places the generated code under the target directory, it doesn't put src/test/java on the classpath before it executes

Answer (score 2):

You should bind to the process-test-classes phase
Instead of
`<phase>process-test-classes</phase>`
It should be
`<phase>process-test-classes</phase>`